# What is the joint density of a drifted Brownian motion reflected below at a positive number and its running maximum?

Tags: brownian-motion

```
Suppose $W^{\mu}_t$ is a Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and $Y_t$ represents the reflecting process of $x+W^{\mu}_t$ ($0<x<b$) which is reflected  at $b$.
```

Suppose $0<x<b$. What is the joint distribution/density for $Y_t,\max_{0\le s\le t}Y_s$? Or  what is  $P(Y_t\in dy,\max_{0\le s\le t}Y_t>0)$?